# Got this error in play console kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

[image: Play console screenshot]    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: 
      at com.videoplayer.VideoPlayerActivity.onStart (VideoPlayerActivity.kt:224)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1395)
      at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7361)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3163)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:180)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:165)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:142)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:70)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1970)

Defining variables

```
private var captionIconVisibility: Boolean = false
    private  var videoStarted: Boolean=false
    private  var lastItemPosition: Int = 1
    private  var itemsCount: Int = 1
    private var videoWatchedTime: Long=0
    private var isPreparing: Boolean=true
    private lateinit var currentPlayingPlayList: List<ObjectVideo>
    private lateinit var sharedPrefMemory: SharedPrefMemory
    private lateinit var mCastApplication: CastApplication
    private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer
    private var isAdPlaying: Boolean =false
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
  //  private lateinit var dtm: DTM
    private lateinit var adPlayerManger: AdPlayerManger
    private var podSize = 1
    private var adType = "midroll"
    private var videoPaused: Boolean = false
    private lateinit var objectVideo: ObjectVideo
    var currentPlayingVodPosition = 0
    private var previousVideoPositionNumber=-1
    private var playBackPosition:Long=0
    private var numberOfVideoWatched: Int=0
    private var isCaptionsOff : Boolean = false
    private var isInfoLayoutVisible:Boolean = false
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityVideoPlayerBinding
    private lateinit var videoPlayerActivityVM: VideoPlayerActvityVM
    private var midAdPositionList = ArrayList<Long>()
    private var runnable: Runnable? = null
    private val mHandler: Handler = Handler()
    private var watchedVideoStatus: HashMap<String, Long>? = null
    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior :BottomSheetBehavior<View>
    private lateinit var bottomSheetRv: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var bottomSheetPlaylistAdapter: BottomSheetPlaylistAdapter
    private var bottomSheetList = ArrayList<ObjectVideo>()
    private var resumedPosition:Long=0
    private var pageNumber:Int =1
    private var url : String = ""
    private var isPreviousClicked: Boolean = false
    private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat
    private lateinit var vods:ArrayList<ObjectVideo>

    companion object {
         var dtm:DTM = DTM()
      //    var vods: ArrayList<ObjectVideo> = ArrayList()
    }
```

My OnCreate method

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_video_player)

        // flags to make media player screen full screen
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.bottomsheetView.bottomSheetLayout)
        bottomSheetRv = binding.bottomsheetView.bottomSheetRv


        sharedPrefMemory = SharedPrefMemory(this, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, true)

//        val mToolbar = binding.toolbarMediaPlayer as Toolbar
//        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
//        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        val intentObj = intent
      //  dtm = intentObj.getSerializableExtra("dtm") as DTM

      try {
          vods = dtm.videoArrayList

          bottomSheetList = vods
          currentPlayingVodPosition = dtm.position
          Log.d("loggingurl",vods[currentPlayingVodPosition].videoUrl);
          url = dtm.url
          if (!(vods.size>0 && currentPlayingVodPosition<vods.size)){
              finish()

          }
          binding.movie = vods[currentPlayingVodPosition]
          mediaPlayer = PlayerBuilder.getMediaPlayer(this, dtm, vods)
          objectVideo = vods[currentPlayingVodPosition]

      }
      catch (e:java.lang.Exception){
          Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }

        bottomSheetBehaviorCallbacks()
        binding.infoImg.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.repeatImg.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.captionImg.setOnClickListener(this)


        videoPlayerActivityVM = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[VideoPlayerActvityVM::class.java]

        videoPlayerActivityVM.getMoreVideosList().observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer<List<ObjectVideo>> { moreVideosList ->
            if (moreVideosList.isNotEmpty()) {
                bottomSheetList.addAll(moreVideosList)
                bottomSheetPlaylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                mediaPlayer.updatePlayList(moreVideosList)
            } else {
                GlobalObject.hasMoreDataMap[url] = false
            }


        })

        mCastApplication = CastApplication(this, this)
        mCastApplication.createSessionManager()
```

Below is my OnStart Method

```
 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("LifeCycle", "OnStart is called")
        if (true) {
            player = mediaPlayer.getPlayer()
            isCaptionsOff = sharedPrefMemory.subtitlePreference
            updateCaption()
            player.addListener(this)
            binding.exoPlayerView.player = player
            binding.exoPlayerView.setOnClickListener(this)

            //var pos:Long=0

            mediaPlayer.playVideo(dtm.position,videoPlayerActivityVM.getSeekTime(objectVideo,videoPaused,resumedPosition))

            setBottomSheetPlayList()

            videoPaused = false

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please get us more code, we don't know where you have defined your variables and have initialized them or not

Comment: edited my code with oncreate and variables defined

Comment: You haven't initialized 'player' in oncreate function

Comment: but initialized in onstart

Comment: initialize it in oncreate to see issue will be solved or not

Comment: not good practice to initiallize exoplayer in oncreate

Comment: If you defined it in oncreate your error will be solved?

Comment: no, why i am getting this error , thats my question and app is crashing on certain devices not all

Comment: If it is crashing only in some devices, maybe your dependencies is only for some APIs

Comment: In your AVD, try your app with Android 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have line numbers so I'm just guessing here.

Take a look at `onCreate`:

```
try {
    vods = dtm.videoArrayList
    // ...
    mediaPlayer = PlayerBuilder.getMediaPlayer(this, dtm, vods)
    objectVideo = vods[currentPlayingVodPosition]
} catch (e: Exception) {
      Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

So when `PlayerBuilder.getMediaPlayer(this, dtm, vods)` or anything before that fails

1. `mediaPlayer` remains uninitialized,
2. user gets a toast but you as a developer get no exception report,
3. `player = mediaPlayer.getPlayer()` happens during `onStart` which casues a crash because (1).

I don't have a fix for you, the code is huge, hard to read and hard to reason about. Good luck fixing it.

Comment: you have valid point , so what if i initilize mediaplayer in the catch block as well?

Comment: If it caused the try block to fail it will crash in catch block. If the app can continue running without media player, make the variable nullable and deal with it accordingly in `onStart`. Definitely log the exception to Crashlytics so you know why it failed to initialize.

Comment: will initilize it in oncreate and will check

Comment: most probably your answer is right because it will be happening so i need to figure out but i am accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

This error means that a `property` with `lateinit` was accessed before it got initialised.

Based on the code you provided I can't tell which field it is but on line 224 check the property you are accessing because it is not set yet.

Comment: if (true) { // this is line number 224 but app is not crashing i tested on many devices but crashing only here